Facing MissingPluginException with Flutter Module in Host Android App
I’m currently working on integrating a Flutter module into an existing Android project and am facing an issue with MethodChannels. I’ve made some progress but hit a roadblock and would appreciate your insights.
Here’s what’s happening:
Setup:

I’ve successfully added a Flutter module to my host Android app, and the module is running fine.
I’m now trying to establish a MethodChannel for communication between the host Android app and the Flutter module.

Problem:

I added the MethodChannel in the host Android app, following the Flutter documentation.
However, when I invoke the method, it throws the following error

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launchSDK on channel com.unikrew/bvs)


I suspect the issue lies in the way I’ve implemented the MethodChannel or where I’ve initialized it.

Workaround Attempt:
Out of curiosity, I tried moving the MethodChannel implementation into the .android folder inside the Flutter module to see if that resolves the issue.
Surprisingly, when I do this and run the project, everything works fine.
However, I know this is not the appropriate solution, as the MethodChannel should ideally be handled in the host Android app for better separation of concerns and maintainability. I’m looking for a proper way to address this.
Questions:
What is the best way to add a MethodChannel when integrating a Flutter module with a host Android app?
Could this issue be related to plugin registration or lifecycle callbacks?
